# Antiderivative of piecewise function

Tags: integration

I want to calculate the anti-derivative of: $$ f(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        -\sin(x) & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
        1-x^2 & \mbox{if } x<0
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
such as $F(\pi/2)=0$

I calculated both antiderivatives, thus I did get $\cos(x)$ for the first one and $x-x^3/3$.
Question is to calculate $F(\pi)$ +$F(-1)$.
But If I calculate that with null constant, I get $-5/3$ which is wrong.

Then could you help me on which value should I give to the constants $C_1+C_2$ ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you calculated that antiderivative for $x \geqslant 0$ is $\cos x +c_1$ and for $x<0$ it is $x-\frac{x^3}{3}+c_2$. As antiderivative should be continuous we have $c_1+1=c_2$, so we obtain
$$F(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \cos(x)+c & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
        x-\frac{x^3}{3}+c+1 & \mbox{if } x<0
    \end{array}
\right.$$
now you can get $c$ from condition $F(\pi/2)=0$

Answer (score 1):

The question, as you stated it, is ill-posed. The anti-derivative of a piecewise continuous function like $f$ is defined up to a constant on each "piece". Thus, the anti-derivatives of $f$ are
$$
F(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \cos(x)+C_1 & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
        x-\frac{x^3}{3}+C_2 & \mbox{if } x<0
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
With the condition that $F(\pi/2)=0$, we can solve for $C_1$, but we do not have enough information left to solve for $C_2$. Presumably, the question is implicitly assuming something; if I had to guess, it's assuming that $F(x)$ is continuous. If so, then you can use the equation
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}F(x) = \lim_{x\to0^-}F(x)
$$
to solve for $C_2$.